# PC immediately after start periodically switch off/on

Tags: hardware-failure

When I start my PC immediately switch off and immediately switch on and this occurs periodically so I have to detach a power cable. I'm convinced that it is motherboard failure. Has someone some experience with this type of failure?

Answer (score 0):

My old pc had this problem (Turn on > Turn off after 1 second > Turn on again after few seconds) after I broke one of the motherboard's PCI slots when I was trying to remove my massive graphic card. so yes, it *can* be a motherboard failure.

Answer (score 0):

it may be the PSU that is not giving proper voltages to the motherboard, this can be caused by  bad capacitors inside the PSU

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit?